# Can the Xbox One be jail broken/modded?

Tags: xbox-one, mods

I have an Xbox one X. I was wondering if it could be jail broken or modded without a computer. I have only found outdated methods of methods that require a computer. Can anyone help?

Comment: @Lemon It's not asking for more information, so it's not a comment. If you don't know what the question is asking, leave a comment to that effect, not an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jailbreaking electronics refers to customers being able to escape the limitations imposed by manufacturers, usually related to the operating system. As of now, the Xbox One cannot be jailbroken.

Modding may refer to installing custom hardware, most often related to the console's visuals or to installing modified code to run all or parts of the hardware. This is currently not possible. Furthermore, this would certainly require another device of some kind to provide the code.

Technical reasons for these limitations are related to lessons learned from the previous console generation. The Xbox One runs signed code, which means you cannot simply alter existing code without going through the certification process. While you can circumvent this with the developer mode of the Xbox One, you would still not be able to customize the operating system as the developer mode is run by the OS. Furthermore, other security features, such as sandboxing or running dedicated VMs. separate environments which makes it hard to use memory exploits to insert custom code.